# Select Records from First OR occurence within a multiple AND/OR T-SQL statement within a function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL (example):

```
SET @Return_Value = = (SELECT Top 1
                          (CASE WHEN .... THEN ColumValue1 ELSE ColumValue2 END)
                        FROM TableA WHERE (Lots of AND Statements)
                         AND
                          (
                            (bla1)
                            OR
                            (bla2)
                            OR
                            (bla3)
                        )
```

The bla1, etc are logic to retrieve colum values from TableA. How can I return the values from bla1 if they were found without executing bla2 or bla3 because those might overwrite what I'm looking for?   In other words I only want to execute OR statements if the previous one didn't find data, all this within a function.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly? You want to mark your results with some additive so you can see in those results due to which `where`-clause they were found?

Comment: Your example is pretty vague, but maybe you could use coalesce?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

Comment: Actually no, I want to return only the data (if found) from the first OR statement whichever OR statement that happens to be

Comment: Deepshikha, I really liked your solution and tried it but records were returned from more than one case statement, weird, not sure why. Roman Pekar, I haven't tried your solution, not sure how to fit it in to what I have, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a case expression as :

```
SET @Return_Value = (SELECT Top 1
                          (CASE WHEN .... THEN ColumValue1 ELSE ColumValue2 END)
                        FROM TableA WHERE (Lots of AND Statements)
                         AND
                          ( 1 = case when condition1 then 1
                                case when condition2 then 1
                                case when condition3 then 1
                                end
                          );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `order by`, like

```
select Top 1
    CASE WHEN .... THEN ColumValue1 ELSE ColumValue2 END
FROM TableA
WHERE
   (Lots of AND Statements) AND
   (
        (bla1) OR
        (bla2) OR
        (bla3)
   )
order by
   case
       when (bla1) then 1
       when (bla2) then 2
       when (bla3) then 3
       else 999
   end
```

Or you can try to simplify it (but you have to check performance):

```
select Top 1
    CASE WHEN .... THEN ColumValue1 ELSE ColumValue2 END
FROM TableA
    outer apply (
        select
            case
                when (bla1) then 1
                when (bla2) then 2
                when (bla3) then 3
            end as T
    ) as C
WHERE
   (Lots of AND Statements) and
   C.T is not null
order by C.T
```

or, for example, you can use `union`, something like this:

```
with cte as (
    select Top 1
        CASE WHEN .... THEN ColumValue1 ELSE ColumValue2 END as data
    FROM TableA
    WHERE
        (Lots of AND Statements)
), cte2 as (
    select top 1 data, 1 as c from cte where (bla1)
    union all
    select top 1 data, 2 as c from cte where (bla2)
    union all
    select top 1 data, 3 as c from cte where (bla3)
)
select top 1 data
from cte2
order by c
```